# fill between and axis equal not getting on (pgfplots)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I'm trying to visualise the area under the curve in the first quadrant of a function, say f(x) = 6-2x.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal,
    axis lines=middle,
    xtick={3},
    ytick={6},
    domain=0:3,
    ]
\addplot[name path=f, samples=400, blue] {6-2*x};
\addplot[name path=g, samples=400, draw=none] {0};
\addplot [color=blue!20] fill between[of=f and g, soft clip={domain=0:3}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This code produces

[image]

as is, but if I comment out `axis equal,`, I get

[image]

which is closer to the desired behaviour.

Why can't fill between and axis equal get along?

Comment: The are a number of different ways to get it to work, but the best is to reduce the number of samples (2 will do).  You might add [axis on top].

Comment: @JohnKormylo: thank you, this fixed it! I would be curious to know the explanation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/139) was fixed in the just released PGFPlots v1.16.
Thus, your MWE now works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I believe this to be a bug in PGFPlots.  For your particular example, there is actually another way to achieve the same effect that will work with rescale, but otherwise, it seems that changing the `unit vector ratio` property will, in general, break `fill between`.

## Fix for given plot

Firstly onto addressing your particular plot, you can use the `\closedcycle` command which allows you to fill down to the horizontal axis.  Note that `\closedcycle` draws a *closed* shape and thus has edges at the top, bottom and sides which may not always be desirable (in which case, you might prefer `fill between`).  Alternatively, the filling and the desired edge can be plotted separately with:

```
\addplot [draw=blue] {f(x)};
\addplot [draw=none, fill=blue, fill opacity=0.2]
         {f(x)} \closedcycle;
```

though this is now getting somewhat convoluted.

Fortunately, in this instance this can all be avoided since the two axes can very conveniently hide everything so long as they are drawn on top using the `axis on top` key:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=middle,
      axis on top,
      axis equal,
      ytick={6},
      xtick={3},
      samples=400,
      domain=0:3,
    ]
    \addplot [
      draw=blue,
      fill=blue,
      fill opacity=0.2
    ] {6-2*x} \closedcycle;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that to draw a straight line between two points, it is generally easier to use:

```
\addplot [...] coordinates {
    (0, 6)
    (3, 0)
  } \closedcycle;
```

Both options achieve the same effect:

[image: output 1]

## Bug with `fill between`

Now onto the issue with the filling.  The `axis equal` is equivalent to setting

```
unit vector ratio={1 1 1},
unit rescale keep size=true,
```

and it turns out that the issue is with `unit vector ratio`.  Some ratios work fine, but some other set of ratios don't seem to work.  So adding two more plots to the previous example and testing `fill between`

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=middle,
      axis on top,
      % axis equal,
      unit vector ratio={2 1 1},
      ytick={6},
      xtick={3},
      samples=400,
      domain=0:3,
    ]

    \addplot [
      draw=blue,
      fill=blue,
      fill opacity=0.2
      ] coordinates {
        (0, 6)
        (3, 0)
      } \closedcycle;

    \addplot [
      name path=f,
      draw=red,
    ] {x^2 / 1.5 + sin(360 * x)};
    \addplot [
      name path=g,
      draw=black,
    ] {x^2 / 1.5};

    \addplot [color=red!20] fill between [
      of=f and g,
      soft clip={domain=0:3}
    ];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which generates one of the following, based on the value of the unit ratios, or based on the number of samples used.

[image: output 2: not working]
[image: output 2: working]

This appears to be a bug in PGFPlots and has been reported already by [Stefan Pinnow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/95441/stefan-pinnow) over at:

> [#139 [fillbetween] numerical issues with dense points](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/139/)

Comment: First I want to note that the correct key-value should be `scale mode=stretch to fill` instead of just the value `stretch` (which caused an error when I TeXed it; have a look at [section 10.3 in the `pgfplots` manual on page 302](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=302)).

Comment: Second, I think your suggested bug has nothing really to do with `unit vector ratio` or `axis equal` *alone* (with fill between). If you use in your given example `unit vector ratio={1.5 1 1}` then also changing `samples` to either `800` or `200` will give "another" result. So this behavior *is* a bug, but I think this is only due to numerical issues and so this will most probably be the same issue as already reported in `pgfplots` bug tracker [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/139/).

Comment: Sorry, I was playing around with `scale mode` in case it played a role, but it doesn't in this case (at least, not a significant one).  And you are correct, I was looking at `unit vector ratio` in particular and didn't look at samples, but as you correctly point out, `samples` does have a quite drastic effect.  I'll update my answer to reflect this and also refer to the answer.

Comment: Not a problem. Last I want to point out that the `\closedcycle` solution you provided is "suboptimal", because this only works because of the special "boundary conditions" of this problem. `\closedcycle` not only draws the (diagonal) line, but also/in addition the line first horizontally and then vertically back to the first coordinate. You just can't see it, because it is below the axis line with is drawn on top because of the `axis in top` key. ...

Comment: ... To make that visible you could e.g. change the start of the domain to something different than `0` or simply add `very thick` to the `\addplot` options of the "blue" plot. For that reason I'd prefer also here a `fill between` solution.

Comment: Yes, it is true that the `\closedcycle` option is much much more limited, but given that filling to the axis is fairly common, I think it still has its place and `fill between` can be a bit of overkill in such a scenario.

Comment: Sure, depend on what exactly the task is. Please just see this as comment *for others* not so familiar with the different possibilities. My sum up would be: If you want to show a **function** and the corresponding area below it (or between something), use `fill between` because "additional lines" drawn by `\closedcycle` are **not** part of the function. For all other purposes `\closedcycle` is the much simpler solution.